# How to write a script that accepts input from stdin or a file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bash driver for a awk script that should accept input as `cat text.txt | driver.sh` or `./driver.sh file1.txt file2.txt ... [filen.txt]` for however many files. I have tried using

```
   read var
   gawk -f awk_prac.awk $var
```

This works for piping only. I also tried using a for loop to read all the file names, but that doesn't work for piped text. 
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the dummy filename - is interpreted in gawk as "read stdin". Having no filename args also read stdin.

Comment: There is a magic shell expression for this situation: "${@:--}" expands into all the a quoted list of all the args to the shell, or - if there are none. Many commands take - to mean stdin.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant this is exactly what I was looking for. I had seen that expression elsewhere, but didn't think to use it in that way. That's really useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions, depending on what you intend `cat text.txt | driver.sh` should do (which, by the way, is better written as `driver.sh <text.txt`).

1. Read the *data* from `text.txt`.
2. Read the *pathnames* from `text.txt`.

---

Your "driver" (wrapper, really) script could add `/dev/stdin` to the list of positional parameters if that list is empty:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    set -- /dev/stdin
fi

gawk -f awk_prac.awk "$@"
```

This would make the `awk` script take input from the standard input stream if the wrapper script is called without any arguments.

Note the quoting of `"$@"`.  This would expand to each positional parameter (shell script argument), individually quoted, which means it would work with filenames that had spaces and/or shell globbing characters in their names.

If your `awk` code expects a *single* file per invocation, then use a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    set -- /dev/stdin
fi

for pathname do
    gawk -f awk_prac.awk "$pathname"
done
```

---

If you, by reading standard input mean you want to read *pathnames* from standard input (rather than data to process), then you may want to use `xargs` (as the number of pathnames could exceed the maximum length of the command line generated to call you `awk` script):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    cat
else
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
fi | xargs -r gawk -f awk_prac.awk
```

This passes the pathnames from standard input directly (well, via `cat`) to `xargs` if there are no arguments given to the script.  If there are arguments, these are printed as a newline-delimited list for `xargs` to handle.  Again, the quoting of `"$@"` is essential.

The `-r` option to `xargs` stops the utility from running `gawk` if no data is provided for it by the compound `if` statement. This is a non-standard option, check your `xargs` manual.

If your `awk` code expects a *single* file per invocation, then use `xargs` with `-L 1`.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1 Input from a file

you can write a small script to read file names to operate on from a file.

Example file

```
$ cat /tmp/files.txt
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
```

Script

```
while read -r fileName; do 
    gawk -f awk_prac.awk $fileName; 
done < /tmp/files.txt
```

Output:

```
one.txt
two.txt
three.txt
```

#### 2 Input from stdin

On similar lines, you can also take the input from stdin. You can provide one fileName per line or all filenames on single line, and write a script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Script file **driver.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for argument do
gawk -f awk_prac.awk "$argument";
done
```

**Execution** (you can give multiple files ) :

```
$./driver.sh file1.txt file2.txt ... [filen.txt]
```

If Filenames to be given in **stdin** , can use for loop for every file to run:

```
while read -p "Enter File name : " file
do
gawk -f awk_prac.awk $file
echo "Press Ctrl+C to quit"
done
```

Execution :
Just

```
$./driver.sh
```